# USe Form Builder for BPMN2 app as a HumanTAsk Render

Tags: formbuilder

We need to define a formBuilder for a BPM System (BAsed on JBPM) and we wonder if we can reuse  the formBuilder without form Runner just to define forms for human task and catch the form submit whith a HumanTask Service (implemented by us). It is possible to use form Builder stand alone?